# Game Development Institute?

Tags: education

Can you suggest a game development Institute? I am a newbie programmer and is really interested in developing my own game using C++ or other programming language. I would like to enroll my self in an institution who offers this kind of course?

Comment: Does an [online institute](http://www.gameinstitute.com/) count? if anything, for that price, you'll get *a lot* more content than the same amount in game development books. Also you didn't mention where you're from, but I've heard a lot of praise for [DigiPen](https://www.digipen.edu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with any decent programming course, get the basics down then specialize in one of the fields which are important for games like computer graphics, AI, networking, etc... There are a lot of game courses popping up these days not all of them great quality.

A lot of them focus more on game design than game development, which is strange because for every 5 designers you need 40 developers and 100 artists (I just made up that estimate but it's somewhere in that range).

Source: personal experience, I followed a BSc Computing Science and will now start on my MSc doing the Game & Media development track of another university's Computing Science course

Comment: I always thought you will need 5 developers, 40 designers and about 1000 artists to get it right ;)

Comment: @cli_hlt why? In my mind it works like Roy said...

Comment: What university are you doing the Game & Media MSC?

Comment: 1000 artists, now that would be even more ideal :)
@Jeff Utrecht University (the Netherlands)

Comment: I would like to reinforce... *get the basics down*! This means having a decent general programming foundation before even moving to game development. Also, learn how to debug, and understand the error messages of your compiler, that knowledge is invaluable :) Too often I see beginners jump straight into game development by trying to cut, paste and mix samples that they found online, and when an error message comes up, they end up doing a code dump here or on another forum hoping that someone will fix the code for them, because they're absolutely clueless what the messages mean.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in game development. You can actually learn them online. There are a lot of game development forums and online tutorials around. But if you are really interested in enrolling yourself in an institution, this thread suggested one http://www.techyv.com/questions/basic-questions-regarding-game-development

Answer (score 0):

Train2Game (http://www.train2game.com) offer a games developer course. It is a distance learning course and covers C++ as well as basics of game design. I've been doing it for a few months and it's not too bad.